# Coloured Indication Boxes On Website

Tags: html

What I am trying to do is create a grid of data for clients against days. IE, if their backups worked, they get a green square against that day, in a html page.

Is there any CSS or something else that would do the job to check to see if a text document with date and "success" or "fail" is in a directory, then change the background colour of a box in a html file? I'm planning on creating a folder for each client, then having the text files named "20110201Success" or "20110201Failed"

Thanks for any direction you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do server-side programming to accomplish this. (PHP, ASP, etc.)

In PHP, use something like:

```
function getStatus($date)
{
    if (file_exists("path/to/file/".$date."Success.txt"))
    {
        echo "<div class='greenbox'></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='redbox'></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some server-side code to do this.